What is the meaning of ... (three dots) in import path
I just noticed that I made a typo somewhere in my import paths
import { something } from '../../.../../../../foo';

DEMO
As you can see I have three dots somewhere in there. But this works. I tried to google it but couldn't find anything. In my linux terminal ls ... means 2 directories up. But here is does something else. Can someone explain this feature or give me a link? Thnx

Think you should look at paths in TypeScript.

may ls ... is some kind of alias (sorry not linux but Mac). Anyway. I've added a demo

It is probably a typo. ... does not mean anything special in a path. If ls ... is the same as ls ../.. in your terminal, it is probably a shortcut provided by your shell.

Neither in JavaScript nor in TypeScript, the three dots (...) in your import path have any special meaning. They are treated as part of the directory name. This is why your import statement with the three dots still works, even though it may look unusual.
In your example, ../../.../../../../foo would mean going up four levels from the current directory to find the foo directory.
This notation is not standard or recommended practice for import paths, and it may lead to confusion. It's better to use standard relative paths (../) to navigate up the directory structure.

In more succinct terms, anything/../ === ./. So if you have ../../abc/../ or ../../.../../, it's equivalent to ../../. This behavior may be an artifact of the interpreter/JS engine in use, I would caution using this for something production-grade.

I see now. Instead of the three dots I can place anything in there, it doesn't matter

It doesn't have any special meaning. The way you've written your import makes it redundant. You can have anything in place of ... there and the import will still work.
Basically:
step 1 -- ../ <-- you go 1 dir up
step 2 -- .../ <-- you resolve (...) from 1 dir up
step 3 -- ../ <-- you go 1 dir up from (...) , i.e. where you were in step 1
step 4 -- ../ <-- 2 dir up from your file
step 5 -- ../ <-- 3 dir up from your file

